# Integration inequality from ISI Entrance Examination

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function, whose first and second derivatives are continuous on $[0,2\pi]$ and $f''(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in [0,2\pi]$. Show that $$\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos x dx\ge 0$$.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: We know that $I=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos x dx=[f(x)\sin x]_0^{2\pi}+[f'(x)\cos x]_0^{2\pi}-\int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)\cos x dx\implies I=f'(2\pi)-f'(0)-\int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)\cos x dx$. Now since $f'$ is continuous on $[0,2\pi]$ and $f''(x)>0$, $\forall x\in (0,2\pi)$, we can conclude that $f'$ is strictly increasing on $[0,2\pi]$. This implies that $f'(2\pi)>f'(0)\implies f'(2\pi)-f'(0)>0$. Therefore if we can show that $\int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)\cos xdx\le 0$, then we can conclude that $I\ge 0$, right?

Comment: Edit your post to add the last comment.

Answer (score 3):

Let us complete your attempt.

According to the mean value theorems for definite integrals there is a $c\in (0,2\pi)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{0}^{2\pi}f''(x)\cos x\, \mathrm{d}x = \cos(c)\cdot\int_{0}^{2\pi}f''(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \cos(c)(f'(2\pi)-f'(0)).
\end{equation*}
Consequently
\begin{equation*}
 I= (f'(2\pi)-f'(0))(1-\cos(c))\ge 0.
\end{equation*}